# Node iterator failing when being used to instantiate objects

Tags: javascript, while-loop, instantiation

I'm using a JavaScript node iterator to create instances of an object which are attached to elements within the DOM. The following code is what I'm using and it works fine:

```
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    {
        acceptNode: function(node) {
            if (node.attributes['data-sd-autocomplete']
                && node.type === 'text')
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
    },
    false
),
nodeList = [],
node;

SDAutoComplete.fields = [];

while (node = nodeIterator.nextNode())
    nodeList.push(node);

// Add new instances of SDAutoComplete to the fields list
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    SDAutoComplete.fields.push(new SDAutoComplete(nodeList[i]));
}
```

I tried to shorten the code to make it more concise, removing the for loop and replacing the line within the while loop so it directly instantiates with the node variable:

```
while (node = nodeIterator.nextNode())
    SDAutoComplete.fields.push(new SDAutoComplete(node));
```

But this causes the page to hang as if the while loop is getting stuck. Could anyone shed any light on why this is the case?

Comment: What does `new SDAutoComplete()` do? Does it mess with the DOM and send the live iterator into an endless loop?

Comment: It's using the Twitter Typeahead library. Seems that when creating a new Typeahead instance it copies the attached element, thus leading to an endless loop for the iterator. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.